# Angular: component should produce parts of a SVG

Tags: angular, svg

An Angular component normally produces HTML.
If I try to let them produce SVG it failes because it does not know the SVG tags.
Seems it only knows them if the result is inside . But thats not the case here -  is in the parent-component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cbyf99?file=src/app/app.component.ts

My component should produce parts of a SVG.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Using SVG elements in child components**

SVG elements, `<circle>`, `<rect>` etc will not be recognised on their own as there is no parent `<svg>` element. You can resolve this by prepending them with `svg` ie: `<svg:circle>` or `<svg:rect>`

**Child component selector**

You can't use a normal Angular component for the child, as it it inserts a corresponding element into the DOM which interferes with the SVG rendering (ie: `<mycircle>` below):

[image]

To address this, change the selector so it is enclosed in square brackets:

`selector: '[mycircle]'`

You can then use it like a directive and assign it to an svg `<g>` element in the parent:

```
<svg>
  <g mycircle />
</svg>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvnvwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Shouldn't the selector be `'[mycircle]'`?

Comment: The selector on the child 'component' is `[mycircle]` as I've shown above and in the stackblitz. Where it's consumed it has no brackets as per normal Angular syntax: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives